# PHP MYSQL User Form Registration

Tags: php, registration

I tried to a user registration and email verification using PHP, everything responded very well but a certain point after the user has submitted the registration form then the form is posted to `verify.php` then the script will send an activation code to the user's email.

The error is that the moment the activation mail is sent to the user's mail box, the page should display:

> Thank you! An email has been sent to {Form.email}. To complete your registration, click on the email verification link sent to your email address.

Instead, it will automatically refresh the page and redirect the user to `registrationcomplete.php` page. which suppose to come after the user has verified.

I used the following code:

```
    <?php
        require ('Connections.php');
        $activationkey =  mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand();
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
        $state = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
        $add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add']);
        $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $lrname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lrname']);
        $lraccount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lraccount']);
        $wmz = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['wmz']);

        $form_submitt = $_POST['button'];

        if ($form_submitt == true){


        $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (`activationkey`, `name`, `country`, `state`, `add`,    `phone`, `email`, `lrname`, `lraccount`, `comment`, `wmz`, `okpay`, `userid`, `password`,  `status`) VALUES ('$activationkey', '$name', '$country', '$state', '$add', '$phone',  '$email', '$lrname', '$lraccount', '', '$wmz', '', '$userid', '$password', 'verify');";

       mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());



       ##Send activation Email

       $to      = $_POST['email'];

       $subject = "Complete registation";

       $message = "Welcome to sitename!\r\rYou, or someone using your email address, has completed registration at www.sitename.com.\r\r You can complete registration by clicking the following link:\rhttp://www.sitename.com/verify.php?$activationkey \r\rIf this is an error, ignore this email and you will be removed from our mailing list.\r\rRegards,\r\r www.sitename.com Team";

       $headers = 'From: noreply@sitename.com' . "\r\n" .

    'Reply-To: noreply@sitename.com' . "\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


}
?>
<?php

##User isn't registering, check verify code and change activation code to null, status to activated on success



if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])){

  $queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `DBName`.`customers`"; 

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if ($queryString == $row['activationkey']){

       $sql = "UPDATE `DBName`.`customers` SET `activationkey` = '', `status` = 'verified' WHERE `customers`.`id` = $row[id];";

       mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

       echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=registrationcomplete.php'>";

       if (!mysql_query($sql)){

        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

       }

    }

  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Is it ok if the solution uses $_REQUEST instead of $_SERVER?

Comment: BTW, escape all POST-vars in a single command: `$_POST = array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST );`

Answer (score 0):

Replace,

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=registrationcomplete.php'>";
```

to

```
header('location:verify.php?action=success');
exit();
```

Now using the `action` variable you can display the message

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "success"){
   echo 'Thank you message........';
}
```